# Apache htaccess: Block direct access to index.html in a folder

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess

I have the following code in my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # block text, html and php files in the folder from being accessed directly
    RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|html|php)$ error [R=301,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# Prevent file browsing
Options -Indexes
```

To block accessing txt, html, php files in the content folder. It works great and it blocks index.html if access the following URI

```
mysite.com/content/index.html
```

but it's not blocking the index.html content being displayed if it's omitted from URI like:

```
mysite.com/content/
```

How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Comment: I am using XAMPP in my local PC, no URL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to disable the directory index, not blocking anything. Just add this to your .htaccess file:

```
DirectoryIndex none.none
Options -Indexes
```

First line is to tell apache not to serve the "index.html" in case of a user navigates to the folder. More info at [DirectoryIndex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) doc.

Second is to tell apache not to show the content of the folder, because there is no default file to show (First line disable it)

Comment: This will block the root as well :(

Comment: Wrapping <Directory /content> DirectoryIndex none </Directory> like you said worked, thank you!

Comment: Is `none.none` special? I don't see anything about that in the docs. Why doesn't that just try to load mysite.com/content/none.none?

Answer (score 0):

If you add **DirectoryIndex none.none** in the main directory .htaccess file you will disable the main index as well which might not be desired.

Your fix is:

```
RewriteRule ^content/?$ error [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^content/(.*)\.(txt|html|php)$ error [R=301,L]
```

The above line tells Apache to redirect to error all requests to **content** and **content/** as well.

Comment: "...but **it's not blocking the index.html content** being displayed if it's omitted from URI like..."  I think that is what he want.

Comment: That's exactly what the first line of the suggested code do. Even it adds a little bit of paranoid security by handling both cases - the one with slash and the other without it although Apache usually redirects the directory name if without slash to the same with slash at the end.

Comment: In fact your solution will work if he adds just these lines to a separate .htaccess file which resides in the content directory. So yeah, it will work but why to add additional file when you can organize all restrictions and redirects from the main .htaccess. At last I would prefer the more centralized way. It's all depending on the preferences. :)

Comment: Well, there is no need for a second file, the lines can be added in the actual .htaccess. BTW RewriteEngine is less efficient :)

Comment: Sure, it's less efficient because of the regular expressions but that might be felt on really huge performance demanding monsters. Anyway if he puts that code in the main .htaccess he'll lock out mysite.com/ index which would not open its index.php/html anymore. And as far as I understood from the question he needs that functionality just for the mysite.com/content/ path.

Comment: Last one, I'm going to sleep :) . Not neccesary, you could wrap the `DirectoryIndex` inside `<Directory /content> DirectoryIndex none </Directory>`