# NodeJS: User can bypass route handler by navigating directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, directory, cpanel

I'm new to node.js and I've created a login system. My app is in the subdirectory of a domain, for example: https://domain.tld/nrjs/. There are two folders within this app which contain static files. One folder is called `public` and one is called `protected`. When the user connects to the node app at https://domain.tld/nrjs/, they are served the static folder `public` and directed to the `login.html` page. Once they are authenticated they are then served the static folder `protected`, and sent to https://domain.tld/nrjs/index.html which is stored in the `protected` folder. The issue is, it seems whether the app.js sends them the folder or not (whether they have authentication or not), the user can directly link to the folder at https://domain.tld/nrjs/protected/index.html or any other actual file, and it completely ignores any route handlers in my app.js file. I'm using cPanel. Below is my app.js, but it seems like the user can directly link to the file and app.js isn't even involved. I need to be able to prevent the user from accessing the `protected` folder until they have successfully logged in, or preventing them from accessing it at all is fine too, as I will be sending them the files at `/index.html` not `/protected/index.html`.

Structure:

```
public_html/
│
└───nrjs/                 (node.js app is in subdirectory) 
    │   app.js
    │
    ├───public/
    │       login.html    (Publicly accessible login page)
    │
    └───protected/
            index.html    (Private home page, should not be directly accessible)
```

Here is my app.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const session = require('express-session');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const app = express();
const basePath = '/nrjs';
const saltRounds = 10;

let users = [
    { username: 'admin', password: 'password' },
    { username: 'user1', password: 'password1' },
    { username: 'user2', password: 'password2' }
];

Promise.all(users.map(user =>
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltRounds).then(hash => {
        user.password = hash;
    })
)).then(() => {
    console.log('Users initialized with hashed passwords');
});

app.use(session({
    secret: 'KAL783BB4HJK1P90V3',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(basePath, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.session.user && req.path !== '/login.html' && req.path !== '/login') {
        return res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html');
    }
    next(); 
}

app.use(basePath, checkAuthenticated, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'protected')));

app.post(basePath + '/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password } = req.body;
    const user = users.find(u => u.username === username);

    if (user) {
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error during password comparison:', err);
                return res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html?error=An error occurred');
            }

            if (isMatch) {
                req.session.user = user.username;

                const loginLog = `Successful login by ${user.username} at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n`;
                fs.appendFile('logs/success_login_attempts.log', loginLog, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error writing to login log file:', err);
                    }
                });

                res.redirect(basePath + '/index.html');
            } else {
                const failedLoginLog = `Failed login attempt with username: ${username} at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n`;
                fs.appendFile('logs/failed_login_attempts.log', failedLoginLog, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error('Error writing to failed login log file:', err);
                    }
                });

                res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html?error=Incorrect username or password');
            }
        });
    } else {
        const failedLoginLog = `Failed login attempt with username: ${username} at ${new Date().toLocaleString()}\n`;
        fs.appendFile('logs/failed_login_attempts.log', failedLoginLog, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error writing to failed login log file:', err);
            }
        });

        res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html?error=Incorrect username or password');
    }
});

app.get(basePath + '/login', (req, res) => {
    res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html');
});

app.get(basePath + '/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session.destroy();
    res.redirect(basePath + '/login.html');
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I've tried putting all kinds of route handlers at the top of the page, and did a catch-all route handler and it still let the user directly navigate to the file.

Example:

```
app.get('/nrjs/protected', (req, res) => {
    res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
});
```

I also tried using a route wildcard:

```
app.get('/nrjs/protected/*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(403).send('Access Denied');
});
```

and when trying to catch everything they can still navigate to the protected file:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.status(404).send("Sorry, the page you're looking for doesn't exist.");
});
```

I have also tried with blocking access to the `protected` folder using `.htaccess` and got a 503 error on routes outside of the `protected` folder.

**Edit:** I've moved the node app outside of the web directory, and therefore the user's can no longer directly navigate to the apps static files, fixing the issue. However, I'd still like to know if there is a way to prevent the user from navigating the files if I did store the node app within the web directory. I can confirm that there is no session set when the user successfully navigates to the protected directory. Thanks!

Comment: while trying static files, to eliminate browser cache it's better to append some query like index.html?123 .
 everything seems normal, also please check if really session.user is falsy, perhaps  session creating some value before reaching protected-static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the files that can be accessed via HTTP such as `.jpg`, `.css`, `.js`, `.txt` or `.html` that are in your `public` or `protected` directory can be accessed in the browser simply by navigating to them in the url. This because whatever is serving files from the `public_html/` directory (Apache likely) is the one serving up `protected/index.html` and not express. Here is an illustration.

This is your domain:

```html
https://domain.tld
```

User makes a `GET` request to this file:

```html
https://domain.tld/pancakes.html
```

Apache (for arguments sake) serves up the file from here:

```html
/var/www/html/public_html/pancakes.html
```

User then makes a `GET` request to this route for example:

```html
https://domain.tld/nrjs/login
```

Well you must have something listening for traffic on port 443 to `https://domain.tld/nrjs` and routing it to port 3000 so that express can pick it up.

When express gets that request on port 3000 it then sends a `redirect` to `nrjs/login.html`. Well you are using the `app.use(basePath, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` middleware so express sees `login.html` in the `public` folder and just sends the html back to the user.

Next the user sends a `POST` request to here:

```html
https://domain.tld/nrjs/login
```

Again its re-routed to port 3000 and after a few password validations etc express `redirects` to `nrjs/index.html`. It passes through the `static` middleware looking at the `public` directory and can't find it. Then it passes through the `static` middleware looking at the `protected` directory and bingo, it serves up `index.html`.

Now what you have is a `checkAuthenticated` middleware making sure it's an authenticated user looking for `index.html` but that will only work for requests made on port 3000 to `https://domain.tld/nrjs/index.html`.

If the user navigates to:

```html
https://domain.tld/nrjs/protected/index.html
```

Then that it looks like Apache is just picking that up on port 443 and serving it up. Express doesn't have any route handlers for `protected/index.html`, it only has `nrjs/index.html`.

My advice would be:

1. Get rid of the `protected` folder all together.
2. Move `index.html` to the same directory as `app.js`.
3. Change this:

```js
res.redirect(basePath + '/index.html');
```

to this

```js
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
```

4. Delete this:

```
app.use(basePath, checkAuthenticated, express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'protected')));
```

5. Add this:

```
app.get(basePath + '/index', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
});
```

Now the only way a user can access `index.html` is by going through the login process or by going through the `https://domain.tld/nrjs/index` route which they will need to pass the `checkAuthenticated` middleware first.

Comment: This is a great response, and I appreciate the well put together explanation. I am just going to wait a bit and see if anyone else provides other solutions, or one that is a bit more suitable for large amounts of protected files. If no one else responds, (or no better responses), I'll accept the answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. If you have a large number of protected files and you're in a position to refactor then I would look at migrating those static files (index.html, login.html) to a view engine such as [EJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs) or [Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars) or [Express-Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars). That way it's only route handlers that can route requests to those files. @Jacob

Comment: Ya since I initially posted this question I've started using pug and EJS. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have a webserver running as wel?

If so then you need to config this not to share folders. With Apache this is done by adding a .htaccess file.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20256297/2087070) explains how to configure it.